# How to control Jquery Testimonial Speed

Tags: jquery, slider

I am new to this website and new to Jquery. So seniors please help me to making delay in a testimonial slider which you guys can see here...

http://www.parorrey.com/blog/front-end-development/jquery-testimonials-slider-with-navigation-and-effects-using-cycle-plugin-multiple-sliders-on-same-page/

or

here is the code

```
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


      $('#testimonials2')
    .after('<div id="nav2">')
    .cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, scrollRight, shuffle
        pager:  '#nav2'
     });
});
</script>
```

I am using this slider but problem is this one is very fast and I can't see any option to set the delay so that user can read easily. Please help me in this regard or refer me any jquery testimonial slider which has button to navigate and i can control the speed.

Thanks alot and waiting for quick replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this line down in the js plugin:

```
timeout: 4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions
```

So if you wanted, you could download the file, edit this to make it however long you want, and reference it locally instead of on github.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you:

```
$('#s2').cycle({ 
    fx:      'scrollDown', 
    speedIn:  2000, 
    speedOut: 500, 
    easeIn:  'easeInCirc', 
    easeOut: 'easeOutBounce', 
    delay:   -2000 
});
```